# How to get only one traefik frontend for two grouped backends?

Tags: docker, traefik

I start two docker backends from the same image and group them together:

```
# docker run --label traefik.backend=myapp --label traefik.frontend.rule="Host:myapp.ex.com" wazaa
# docker run --label traefik.backend=myapp --label traefik.frontend.rule="Host:myapp.ex.com" wazaa
```

I was expecting to get only one frontend (common to both backends), but instead got this:

[image]

What else should I do to get only one frontend? (I do not even understand why two are created in the first place, they both have the same `Host` and point to the same backend (both these facts are expected and intended, the two separate frontends are not))